# VMWare Player shared folders become disabled

Tags: vmware-player

I have a Windows 7 Ultimate (64 bit) host running VMWare Player 6.0.1, hosting a Linux Mint 13 (KDE, 32 bit) guest.  It works fine, except for a problem which has recently cropped up - my shared folders stop working, and the option to manipulate them becomes greyed out.  By Googling I've discovered that if I type:

> sudo vmware-config-tools.pl

(and then answer a few questions as the script runs) my folders (and the option to reconfigure them) returns to life.  I've been using this VM for a few months now and this has just started happening in the last week or so.  I'm not aware that I'm doing anything differently, and I can't think of any software I've installed/changes made to either environment which can explain this. Both OSes are regularly patched, however.  The folders don't stop working during a session; it seems to happen when I restart the guest session.

Any ideas why this is happening, and how I can make my shared folders "stick"?

Comment: I'm thinking that VMWare has a bug... give a look [here](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1027646) if things doesn't get better you might really want report a bug.

Comment: I might do that.  I'm wondering, now, whether this problem coincided with my installing Player 6.0.1.